# How to show one gallery with it's photos

Tags: php, laravel

I am doing page with gallery and if I click on one of them, it will redirect me to single gallery page and supposed to show photos of that gallery.

When I get on the page of actual gallery, there is nothing in gallery object.

When I do `Gallery::with('photos')->get()`. This will give me every gallery with its photos. I want photos only from actual gallery.

Thanks.

```
//Photo model


class Photo extends Model
{
   public function gallery()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Gallery');
    }
}

//Gallery model



class Gallery extends Model
{
        public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }

        /**
     * Get the photos of this gallery.
     */
    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Photo');
    }
}


//show metod in GalleryController

   public function show(Gallery $gallery)
    {

           $gallery->load('photos');

            return compact('gallery');

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in the gallery because you are not returning a view.

This line:

```
 return compact('gallery');
```

Needs a view, something like:

```
return view("somethingFolder.somethingView", compact('gallery'));
```

OR if you are just showing a model like with an ajax pull, you can use something like this:

```
    $view = view('somefolder.someview', compact('gallery'));

    $sections = $view->renderSections(); // returns an associative array of 'content', 'pageHeading' etc

    return $sections['modalContent']; // this will only return whats in the content section
```

Then in your view, `$gallery->photos` will give you a collection of the photos for that gallery.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment, I tried this what you write, but in my view when i do {{ $gallery->photos }} there is still empty array

Comment: OK, I did it, I forgotted one "L" in word "gallery".. This are kind of mistakes you looking at for hours and u cant see it.. ah